# HyperLink to the first column in Datatables?

Tags: java, jsp, hyperlink

Below is the code for the radio button,I would like to make the first Column as
 hyperlink instead of radio button and pass it on to the next jsp page.
 and also have any idea of working on datatables values placing in the PIECHART.

Can u please help me ?

```
  "aoColumnDefs" : [
      {"fnRender" : function(oObj){  return '<div align="center">
      <input name="selectedAcccountId" type="radio" property = "selectedAcccountId"  
             value="'+ oObj.aData[0]+'">  
      </div>';},
 "aTargets" : [0]
  }],
```